GeneralServiceException during deployment of cloudformation of step function
The whole error is not very descriptive:

Resource handler returned message: "null (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 413; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: 763519f3-22d7-761c-a321-a187fd8c28d2, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

Is there any hint on how to get more context or what it could be about?
I thought it was a general service failure in eu-central-1 first, then i looked at quotas but none really made sense.
